# Unable to call http://localhost Azure Function from https://localhost node app

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have one Node.js Azure function running on a Windows 11 system at http://localhost:7071/api/FunctionName.

I can execute the function by calling it from a browser window no problem.

Now when I call it from another node app running on localhost with axios or fetch, I get an ECONNREFUSED error.

I get the same results whether I'm running from NPM start or inside VS Code.  It works fine on one system.

Any suggestions? - this used to work no problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Try with this code snippet - https://codeshare.io/6pyBjm

Comment: strange - it is working fine on one system, where the http:// function is called successfully.  It's nothing to do with the code, just configuration.

Comment: Could you please provide what configuration you have done!

Comment: I just figured out a fix - calling the localhost IP address directly works.  http://127.0.0.1/api/FunctionName.

Answer (score 5):

I just figured out a fix - calling the localhost IP address directly works: http://127.0.0.1/api/FunctionName.

Now I need to figure out what caused the configuration change.

Answer (score 2):

there has been a breaking change on dns resolution for localhost since node 17.

Your solution works fine because providing the Ip explicitly prevents the dns resolution mechanism.

other possible solutions:

1- force the node app to use ipv4 first:

```
const dns = require('dns');
dns.setDefaultResultOrder('ipv4first');
```

2 - downgrade node to version 16

this issue is also reported on github:
[#40702](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40702)

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ." And keep in mind that linked content is not considered part of an answer here, a summary of how the solution is achieved is needed here.

Comment: And please point out the difference of the summarised solution to the solution in the already existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74438716/7733418